# Проблемы с BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте представлена работа BottomNavigationView, необходимо убрать Lable BottomNavigationViewApp.
Все перепробовал при изменении темы в Манифесте приложение крашится. Даже менял тему не для всего приложения а для Activity отдельно. Может кто-то сталкивался помогите пожалуйста. 
P.S.
Использую: Java и View AndroidX

Comment: нужно было дополнить ваш первый вопрос, а не публиковать новый

Comment: спасибо удалил первый вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта полоска наверху называется тулбаром. Я не знаю какую именно вы тему используете, и что в вашем понимании означает убрать, но тем не менее можно установить пустой title или убрать toolbar вообще через тему. Устанавливаем программно пустой заголовок:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

при этом полоска останется. Либо убрать полоску через тему в манифесте:

```
<activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

и добавить стиль:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Так же есть третий вариант - скрыть тулбар вообще:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

при этом сама тема останется нетронутой.

### UPDATE

Тогда вам не подойдет ни один из вышеперечисленных способов, так как вам нужен тулбар. Для того чтобы у тулбара была нужная вам разметка или поведение нужно добавить такие строки:

```
supportActionBar!!.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
supportActionBar!!.setCustomView(R.layout.customLayout)
```

Не получится скрыть тулбар темы и показать ваш, так как тема приложения будет без тулбара. В коде выше `customLayout` это ваша разметка.

[Вот есть туториал](https://medium.com/@qureshi.ayaz29/custom-toolbar-in-android-3818a0740942) в котором все красиво показано.

Comment: 1) Манифест пробовал приложение вылетает при открытии Activity. 2) Стиль тоже не работает должным образом. Тулбар не скрывал, я так понимаю это в Activity.сlass прописывать ?

Comment: если вылетает значит вы обращаетесь как-то к данному виджету или к другому элементу которого нет в теме, либо приложите лог падения, либо посмотрите на какой строке падает

Comment: дело в том что пока тулбар не трогаю Activity функционирует нормально

Comment: я вот не могу понять вам его вообще скрыть нужно или просто текст в нем убрать?

Comment: Мне его нужно скрыть, а на его место поставить свой Custom tool bar

Comment: обновил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, тогда попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него